# Inline SVG making parent div bigger

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a small dashboard app. Since it's going to be on a dashboard, I want to avoid having to scroll at all costs. I therefore set height/width of html/body tags to 100%, and am using percentages everywhere else as I will not know screen sizes.

However when I add an inline SVG, when I set width to 100% on the SVG element it forces the parent DIV to get bigger to fit the SVG, instead of stopping when it gets to the smaller size.

It's hard to explain, but I did a JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5khkzgk8/4/

It's the basics layout of the app. the SVG is a black rectangle the fills the svg.

```
svg {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Currently the svg width is 10%, and it works fine. If you increase the percentage 10% by 10% and see how it behaves you will see. What I would like (and would have though happen) is that once it fills the height of the div (in light blue), the SVG would stop scaling up. What happens is it continues scaling up until we get to width=100%, but now the div is so big you need to scroll.

I'd be much grateful for any assistance. I'm just a weekend worrior in frontend/css so I'm really lost at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting `position:absolute` to your svg-wrapper. The height cannot be applied for normally layouted elements

Comment: Aha! using position:absolute on the svg wrapper made it work though it took the whole screen (hiding the menu bar). But! your suggestion had me read more about that attribute (first time I've used it) and it works if I make the container "relative", and then the svg absolute. :) Thanks!